# How to minimize redirects single url in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How to minimize such requests in one?

```
location = /GetFile.ashx {
    return 301 /overview-videos/;
}
location = /products/GetFile.ashx {
    return 301 /overview-videos/;
}
location = /abouts/GetFile.ashx {
    return 301 /overview-videos/;
}
```

Comment: Why you want to do so? Nginx is really efficient in matching exact URIs.

Comment: Because I have a hundred folders for GetFile.ashx ( The old site urls.

Comment: Well, then you should probably use regexp locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A simple solution for the Nginx:**

```
location ~ ^/(.*)GetFile.ashx$ {
     return 301 /overview-videos/;
}
```